# How does java fill a polygon

Tags: java, swing, graphics, polygon, fill

I've wondered for a while now how java fills his polygons, I've been trying it myself with scanline algorithms etc. etc. which have ended quite distorted uptill now, so I got myself wondering how does Java do it? Because that seems quite clear, does it also use scanlines or is it a whole different kind of algorithm? (I've tried searching it in the source but hell, that's a maze.)

Regards

Comment: This will depend on the underlying native libraries that the various graphical toolkits use...

Comment: In other words, no clue? :)

Comment: Yes and no.  I'm not aware how DirectX or OpenGL do it, but that's your next port of call ;)

Comment: See also [*Graphics Gems*](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open JDK sources are [available online](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/). So you can have a look at the code yourself, although you should keep in mind that by looking at that code, an using what you see as “inspiration” for your own code, you're likely subject to the OpenJDK license conditions, so don't have too close a look unless you are willing to use a compatible license for your code.

1. Start at [`share/classes/java/awt/Graphics.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/share/classes/java/awt/Graphics.java), which is the interface containing the `fillPolygon` code you'll likely use. It's an abstract method there, so you'll have to look at classes implementing that interface.
2. [`share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java) is one such. It simply delegates the `fillPolygon` call to a matching call on a [`sun.java2d.pipe.PixelFillPipe`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/pipe/PixelFillPipe.java) object. But since that is only an interface, you'll again have to look for implementations.
3. [`share/classes/sun/java2d/pipe/BufferedRenderPipe.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/pipe/BufferedRenderPipe.java) is one possible implementation. Its `fill` implementation makes use of a `fillSpans` method, the core of which is implemented in native code.
4. [`share/native/sun/java2d/pipe/BufferedRenderPipe.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/share/native/sun/java2d/pipe/BufferedRenderPipe.c) has the corresponding implementation. So once you have, from looking at the code, understood what a span is and how a polygon gets translated into spans, then this *might* tell you how a span gets rendered.

All of the above are just *one* possible code path. It very much depends on what platform you are using, and what you are drawing to. There are different primitives for printing, and different primitives for most platforms. For example, on a (non-accelerated) X11 connection, [`solaris/native/sun/java2d/x11/X11Renderer.c`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/solaris/native/sun/java2d/x11/X11Renderer.c) will simply delegate to [`XFillPolygon`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xfillpolygon). There is also [custom code for OpenGL-based graphics](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/fbd926b20201/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/opengl/OGLRenderer.java), but I can't see a fill optimization in that just now. But it might be good to have a closer look.